# Laravel get language array

Tags: laravel, translate, lang

I get language array using `Lang::get('routes')` but i want get different is current local language without change current local.

How to get language array in other language?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a third argument as locale to the the `Lang::get()` method:

```
echo Lang::get('routes', [], 'en');
```